# How do I create an invoice without product?

Tags: 7, commerce

Am working a project that required generating invoice for customer service payment, 'rent' to be specific. Am still a newbie to drupal environment (I do Wordpress Stuff).

Since the Payment is going to be recurrent I choose Drupal Commerce, but am confuse as to how to configure the module(s) needed.

Features that I need
- Admin created invoice for Client (registered user) with invoice status UNPAID
- Invoice sent to Client via email (PDF format)
- Client Pay at Bank and upload Prove of payment
- Admin change the invoice status to PAID upon Validation.

I could Create Content type for the invoice, but I may not be able to create PDF and mail it to user in which Drupal Commerce would handled well with other Contributed Module.

I should be able to handle it if I can get a kind of guide.

Comment: Are you using 7 or 8. Please tag your post appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the [Commerce Billy module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_billy)

Features

```
Thread safe invoice number generation
Three invoice number generation methods: monthly, yearly, infinite
Configurable pre- an suffix values for invoice numbers
Arbitrary start value for invoice number
"invoiced" status on order entity (thus avoiding separate invoice entity)
Automatic or manual invoicing:
    Automatic: order moved to status "invoiced" on order completion
    Manual: admin moves order to status "invoiced" (VBO possible, Rules components already included)
PDF Generation (commerce_billy_pdf module)
Customizable PDF template
Views integration for PDF download link
Handling of credit memos (canceled orders)
```

Comment: I have study the Combination of  both Commerce and Commerce Billy, but i realise that Commerce Module itself seems to elaborate the whole idea of invoicing. 

For example, I have to create an *Order*, add *Line Item* and a line item must be associated with a *Product SKU*. Which implies that I must have a Product before I can create an order, where are I just need to add Line Item manually and set the price.

Or maybe am new to Drupal Commerce that's why am yet to get the logic